# CDK Assets - Docker load build context failing with Access Denied when using Container.fromImage

Tags: docker, aws-cdk

While using the **ContainerImage.fromAsset()** which builds the Docker image, I am running into an Access denied error during the copy operation (***COPY client $APP_HOME/client***). There is no error if I build the Docker image as is using the docker build command.

I have checked the file permissions and there is nothing wrong. It also does not seem to be related to the long path name and renaming anything in the path fixes the problem.

Tried checking out the code on another computer but same problem.

```
#1 transferring dockerfile: 1.08kB 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 transferring context: 203B 0.0s done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine
#3 DONE 0.9s

#4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11
#4 DONE 2.2s

#5 [stage-1 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine@sha256:048...
#5 DONE 0.0s

#8 [builder 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11@sha256:75be50f146...
#8 resolve docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11@sha256:75be50f146c5d36d11348960359457e2e9303706785cf273739f0dbbea1ba429 done
#8 sha256:f964900200fc1f8473ac70d9da14cde8bae251ffb4a8f4792e2bf9baf6aaac70 0B / 62.24MB 0.1s
#8 sha256:75be50f146c5d36d11348960359457e2e9303706785cf273739f0dbbea1ba429 547B / 547B done
#8 sha256:e878e893d995681f88254eb134ff6ba0bf921aefb7303aa6ef3b5864dd80e45c 742B / 742B done
#8 sha256:6e8a5ad94e6eed735b1da93109529df475d74f360b60d69ce8e40afc15088aed 3.07kB / 3.07kB done
#8 ...

#10 [internal] load build context
#10 transferring context: 15.13MB 0.2s done
#10 ERROR: error from sender: open client\src\app\components\portfolio\portfolioSettings\portfolioSettingsContent\editHierarchy\portfolioSettingsGrid\gridContentMenu: Access is denied.

#8 [builder 1/7] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11@sha256:75be50f146...
#8 CANCELED
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open client\src\app\components\portfolio\portfolioSettings\portfolioSettingsContent\editHierarchy\portfolioSettingsGrid\gridContentMenu: Access is denied.

 ❌  pwcore-dev failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
    at Object.publishAssets (C:\Users\rarora\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\util\asset-publishing.ts:25:11)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.publishStackAssets (C:\Users\rarora\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\cloudformation-deployments.ts:305:7)
    at CloudFormationDeployments.deployStack (C:\Users\rarora\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\cloudformation-deployments.ts:202:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (C:\Users\rarora\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cdk-toolkit.ts:199:24)
    at initCommandLine (C:\Users\rarora\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.ts:267:9)
Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
```

Update 1:
Triaged the issue with an AWS rep. While the underlying root cause is still a mystery, the problem may be Docker related. When we do a CDK deploy, it copies the contents to cdk.out/assets.<some_unique_hash_code>. If we do a native Docker build there, we get the same problem implying that it is related to Docker.

```
C:\git_ws\cdk-service\cdk.out\asset.597677384344d1483275063cf834a0e0fef9a332625cc06b13b39aa9f192da5f>docker build -t service .
[+] Building 0.4s (5/6)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 99B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring context: 176B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.3s
 => => transferring context: 32.27MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.3s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
error from sender: open client\src\app\components\portfolio\portfolioSettings\portfolioSettingsContent\editHierarchy\portfolioSettingsGrid\gridContentMenu: Access is denied.
```

Renaming the assets directory solves the problem. It does not seem to be related to long file path name as adding more characters to the asset directory also solves the problem

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  The build logs on their own usually aren't enough to diagnose a problem.  You cite a couple of specific methods; can you include the code that calls them?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error isn't reproducible if I create a same folder structure. The Dockerfile is pretty simple which copies the content from local filesystem and it fails on that.

This works fine if I just do a normal docker build..so trying to find out what is unique about AWS CDK Asset building process which is resulting into an Access denied error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from Docker using BuildKit which is default now.
https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/1366

Disabling the BuildKit fixes the problem.